# Definition of reflexive Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to understand the definition of reflexive spaces. I wrote in my notes:

If $Y$ is reflexive then for all $\eta\in Y^{**}$, $f\in Y^*$, $\exists y\in Y$ where $\eta(f) = f(y)$.

My question is, is this for all $f$ or there exist some $f$? Wikipedia and Wolfram mathworld are not specific about it.

In Hilbert space it seems like for all $f$, but I have difficulty imagining other spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: The quantification order is wrong - for any $\eta\in Y^{\ast\ast}$ you need to find some $v\in Y$ such that $\eta = \text{ev}_v$, i.e. $\eta(f) = f(v)$ for all $f\in V^{\ast}$.

Comment: I see, yep that makes sense. Thanks!